Почему раклама не отображается полностью?
Есть приложение, контент full_screen.
Но почему-то реклама не показывается полностью и не чёрный фон:

themes.xml:
<style name="Theme.MathBattle" parent="@style/Base.Theme.MyApp">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

</style>

В activity перед onCreate вызывается hideSystemBars():
fun AppCompatActivity.hideSystemBars() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    val windowInsetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )

}

activity_main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>;  

Что не так? не пойму.

копайте в сторону "Edge To Edge"

вот недавно Яндекс исправил подобную ошибку в своем SDK
